# Is there anyway to change Google Maps color scheme through gwt (server-side)

Tags: java, gwt

Is there anyway to change Google Maps color scheme through gwt (server-side), not using JavaScript. It seems the only documentation I've been able to come across involves using JavaScript:

```
map.set('styles', [
  {
    featureType: 'road',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [
      { color: '#000000' },
      { weight: 1.6 }
....
```

Anyway, how to do this in gwt Java server-side?

Comment: Since when is GWT "server-side" ?

Comment: OH i meant client-side gwt maps (in java)...although gwt does have server-side, GWT provides an RPC mechanism based on Java Servlets to provide access to server side resources. This mechanism includes generation of efficent client and server side code to serialize objects across the network using deferred binding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps FusionTable implementation in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579073/google-maps-fusiontable-implementation-in-gwt)