# Google Maps FusionTable implementation in GWT

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to have this exact same functionality in GWT?

```
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'geometry',
      from: '1ertEwm-1bMBhpEwHhtNYT47HQ9k2ki_6sRa-UQ'
    },
    styles: [{
      polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: '#00FF00',
        fillOpacity: 0.3
      }
    }, {
      where: 'birds > 300',
      polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: '#0000FF'
      }
    }, {
      where: 'population > 5',
      polygonOptions: {
        fillOpacity: 1.0
      }
    }]
  });
```

I am trying to implement this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-styling

So far I have managed to implement single style here [Custom coloring of countries in Google Maps : GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29577659/768894) but I want to apply conditional styling as in the given javascript code snippet i.e if #ofbirds > 300 then `fillColor: '#0000FF'`  if #ofbirds > 500 then `fillColor: '#0000FE'`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of painful trial and error I was able to do it. Posting here so that others could benefit.

```
private native FusionTablesLayer createFusionTableLayer()/*-{
    return new $wnd.google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
        select: 'geometry',
        from: '1tJkzVXTv-B2-rFeQVO9bX_vICCvJ9Xq1LU6xog5f'
        },
        styles: [{
            polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#00FF00',
            fillOpacity: 0.3
          }
         }, {
             where: 'birds > 300',
             polygonOptions: {
             fillColor: '#0000FF'
            }
        }, {
          where: 'population > 5',
          polygonOptions: {
          fillOpacity: 1.0
          }
       }]
    });
}-*/;
```